# Kotlin Interface Property: Only require public getter without public setter

Tags: kotlin, interface, properties, scope, set

I am trying to create an Interface that forces its deriving classes to have a certain property, but only with a public getter. Since I don't want to allow changes from outside its private scope, I don't want it to implement a public set.

```
interface Transaction{
   var transferDate: Date get //I only require a get, no set
}

class MoneyTransaction(){
   override var transferDate: Date get private set 
/*private set does not work*/
}
```

Comment: You could define the property as a val, is that enough in your case?

Comment: No sadly not, because I still need to be able to privately change the value within the deriving class.

Comment: You can make the property a `var` when implementing it.

Comment: Implementing this as `val` in interface is proper way to do it. Deriving classes can have private backing `var` field and expose that value thru interface getter.

Comment: So the interface with other classes is only to read the value, I would define a function to that instead and leave to the class that is implementing it to decide how to provide that.

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't notice I could override a val with a var

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A property is an accessor to some data. You'll have a getter and if the property is mutable a setter as well. Therefore you can override any declared `val` property with a `var` property:

```
interface Transaction {
   val transferDate: Date
}

class MoneyTransaction: Transaction {
   override lateinit var transferDate: Date
       private set 
}
```

Note that you don't need to make the property a `lateinit var` if you initialize it with the object; I just added it to have your example compile properly.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @tynn's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027637/1470581), in my case I simply needed an accessor for data coming from another source. For this scenario, given that a value is being initialized with a getter, `val` could be used in place of `lateinit var` and there was no need to indicate `private set`.

As an example in line with the others:

```
interface Transaction {
   val transferDate: Date
}

class MostRecentTransaction(private val repo: AccountRepository) : Transaction {
   override val transferDate: Date
      get() = repo.transactions.first.transferDate
}
```